Screen does not lock in Sonoma
MBP M1, Sonoma 14.4.1, screen does not automatically lock after 5 minutes (and screensaver does not start, either), despite being set to kick in after 5 minutes. Problem 'resolves' with reboot, but comes up again by itself. I have no 3rd party apps that are meant to keep the screen up and awake.
pmset -g assertions
2024-05-11 11:06:30 +0300
Assertion status system-wide:
  BackgroundTask                 0
  ApplePushServiceTask           0
  UserIsActive                   1
  PreventUserIdleDisplaySleep    1
  PreventSystemSleep             0
  ExternalMedia                  0
  InternalPreventDisplaySleep    1
  PreventUserIdleSystemSleep     1
  NetworkClientActive            0
Listed by owning process:
   pid 448(WindowServer): [0x000554a9000987ca] 00:00:00 UserIsActive named: "com.apple.iohideventsystem.queue.tickle serviceID:100000b42 service:AppleHIDKeyboardEventDriverV2 product:Apple Internal Keyboard / Trackpad eventType:3"
    Timeout will fire in 600 secs Action=TimeoutActionRelease
   pid 394(powerd): [0x00053b24000185be] 01:54:30 PreventUserIdleSystemSleep named: "Powerd - Prevent sleep while display is on"
   pid 394(powerd): [0x000554ab00108330] 00:00:24 InternalPreventDisplaySleep named: "com.apple.powermanagement.delayDisplayOff"
Timeout will fire in 276 secs Action=TimeoutActionTurnOff
   pid 453(runningboardd): [0x00054e420001878d] 00:32:56 PreventUserIdleSystemSleep named: "app<application.net.whatsapp.WhatsApp.104338045.104338052(501)>453-2277-18925:Shared Background Assertion 3965 for net.whatsapp.WhatsApp(FinishTask)"
Created for PID: 2277.
   pid 2277(WhatsApp): [0x00006e92000596f4] 157:18:59 PreventUserIdleDisplaySleep named: "net.whatsapp.idletimer"
No kernel assertions.


Please start by taking any of the steps in this support article that you haven't already tried: https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/if-your-mac-sleeps-or-wakes-unexpectedly-mchlp2995/mac

yeah, nothing works

Try setting the screen lock quantum to another value, or turn it off completely, close Settings, reopen, then reset to the value you need. Sometimes changing the settings to something else fixes problems like this.

Please post the output of this shell command: pmset -g assertions

Try quitting WhatsApp.

as if by magic... I tried quitting WhatsApp and now it works.

The pmset output shows that “WhatsApp” is preventing sleep.

yes, but why does it?

You'd have to ask the developer. Probably it can't receive messages when the system is asleep. Check the settings to see whether the behavior is optional (unlikely.)
